# Stand up fleet of docker containers to simulate IOT devices?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm

I'm trying to design a good way to bring up a fleet of docker containers that act as IOT devices, each with a slightly different configuration.

In each container I would haven an app that simulated some hardware device, e.g. temperature sensor, and each one would have a unique "identity". Example `sensor1`, `sensor2`, `sensor3`, etc and some other configurations that could vary.

I would also want to scale up and scale down the number of virtual devices based on the use case being tested.

The ways I can think of doing this would be to either pass unique properties to each container via a shell script, or have each container access a database or some other store where it would retrieve its unique configuration on startup from a pool of available configurations.

This way the same app would run in each container but its configuration would be unique. Then they would start sending data to some endpoint where I process their telemetry payloads as a data stream.

For a Kubernetes solution it would seem the containers would have to connect to some common datastore to get their configuration since it would not be possible to pass a unique set of properties to each container?

Comment: In Kubernetes, pods in a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) do know their own identity.

Comment: @ChrisRTech - can you tell me if you ever made any forward progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Regarding the identity, David already mentioned the [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/).

> Like a Deployment , a StatefulSet manages Pods that are based on an
>   identical container spec. Unlike a Deployment, a StatefulSet maintains
>   a sticky identity for each of their Pods. These pods are created from
>   the same spec, but are not interchangeable: each has a persistent
>   identifier that it maintains across any rescheduling.

2. Regarding the scaling. If I understand you correctly, you need a [ReplicaSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/).

> A ReplicaSet is defined with fields, including a selector that
>   specifies how to identify Pods it can acquire, a number of replicas
>   indicating how many Pods it should be maintaining, and a pod template
>   specifying the data of new Pods it should create to meet the number of
>   replicas criteria. A ReplicaSet then fulfills its purpose by creating
>   and deleting Pods as needed to reach the desired number. When a
>   ReplicaSet needs to create new Pods, it uses its Pod template.

3. For the configuration/properties part, [ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) are what you need.

> ConfigMaps bind configuration files, command-line arguments,
>   environment variables, port numbers, and other configuration artifacts
>   to your Pods' containers and system components at runtime.

Please let me know if that helped.